# How to Add Custom Animations or Actions in Pepper Robot Android Application

Tags: android, pepper, choregraphe

I was trying to add custom action in my sample android pepper robot application but I didn't find any topics about this in the documentation. I read few articles and created few actions using Choreographe tool in windows.

Please tell me how to add this actions to my android project or any way to create it by using android studio itself.

As of now I am able to import all the default animations in the SDK eg:elephant.qianim.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try [lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android)

Comment: @FarshidABZ... Thanks for the help....I got the solution for it. We can do it from the android studio itself. First Right click on your raw folder->select new->Animation Time Line.   it will create new Animation file for you by adjusting the robots components you can create your own animations

Comment: Realy? I thought your searching for complex animation :-)))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not find this [documentation page about the animation editor](https://android.aldebaran.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/animation_editor.html#animation-editor)?
It is as close as possible to Choregraphe's editor, but it is part of the Pepper SDK plug-in in Android Studio.